# Creating an editable list. Code showing no error, but not doing correct function

Tags: python-3.6

I have a problem with my code.
It does not produce an error, but it does not run as expected. I was trying to make a program in which a user can add, edit, delete, view items in a list of computer games.
However, whenever I enter anything into 
the program, it doesn't end the program, but does nothing
What can I do?

```
computerGames = []
response = ""

def askQuestion():
    for each in ('add','delete','edit','view','end'):
    if each == 'view':
        print('Type',each,'to',each,'the list')
    elif each == "end":
        print("Type",each,"to",each,'program')
    else:
        print('Type',each,'to',each,'an item in(to) the list')
response = input("Enter your choice\n").upper()

def add():
    newUserGame = input("Enter a game to add onto the end of the list:\n")
    computerGames.append(newUserGame)
    print(computerGames)
    askQuestion()

def delete():
    userDeleteGame = input("Enter a game to delete:\n")
    if userDeleteGame in computerGames:
        computerGames.remove(userDeleteGame)
    else:
        print('Try again')
        print(computerGames)
        userDeleteGame = input("Enter a game to delete:\n")
    askQuestion()

def view():
    print("This is the current list of games:")
    print(computerGames)
    askQuestion()

def edit():
    editGame = input("Enter the game you want to replace:\n")
    if editGame in compGames:
        gameIndex = compGames.index(editGame)
        editGameNew = input("Enter the new game to replace this one")
        compGames[gameIndex] = editGameNew
    else:
        print("This item is not in the list")
        print(compGames)
        editGame = input("Enter the game you want to replace:\n")
    askQuestion()

askQuestion()

while response != "END":
    if response == "ADD":
        add()
    elif response == "DELETE":
        delete()
    elif response == "VIEW":
        view()
    elif response == "EDIT":
        edit()
```

Doing GCSE Computing, so please excuse my lack of coding ability.
Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version of your code:

```
computerGames = []
response = ""

def askQuestion():
    for each in ('add','delete','edit','view','end'):
        if each == 'view':
            print('Type',each,'to',each,'the list')
        elif each == "end":
            print("Type",each,"to",each,'program')
        else:
            print('Type',each,'to',each,'an item in(to) the list')

    response = input("Enter your choice\n").upper()
    return response

def add():
    newUserGame = input("Enter a game to add onto the end of the list:\n")
    computerGames.append(newUserGame)
    print(computerGames)

def delete():
    userDeleteGame = input("Enter a game to delete:\n")
    if userDeleteGame in computerGames:
        computerGames.remove(userDeleteGame)
    else:
        print('Try again')
        print(computerGames)
        userDeleteGame = input("Enter a game to delete:\n")

def view():
    print("This is the current list of games:")
    print(computerGames)

def edit():
    editGame = input("Enter the game you want to replace:\n")
    if editGame in computerGames:
        gameIndex = computerGames.index(editGame)
        editGameNew = input("Enter the new game to replace this one")
        computerGames[gameIndex] = editGameNew
    else:
        print("This item is not in the list")
        print(computerGames)
        editGame = input("Enter the game you want to replace:\n")



while response != "END":
    response = askQuestion()

    if response == "ADD":
        add()
    elif response == "DELETE":
        delete()
    elif response == "VIEW":
        view()
    elif response == "EDIT":
        edit()
```

The first problem was because of something called scope. At the top of the program, you try to instantiate the variable "response" and then update its value within the askQuestion function. However, the empty string version of response is a global variable and as such can be accessed anywhere within the program but the updated, user input version of response is a local variable and so cannot be accessed outside of that function since you have not returned the new variable Therefore when you compare the value of "response" in the for loop and each if statement, the version of response you get is the empty string. Since you have no else statement to catch an input that does not equal add, delete, view, edit or end, none of the if/elif/(else) statements are triggered  and so the while loop repeats. For that reason, I returned the local variable "response" from the askQuestion function and, within the while loop, set the value of the global variable "response" as the result of the function askQuestion.

I also called the askQuestion function within your while loop instead of at the end of each of the "operative" (for want of a better phrase) functions as it is almost always better not to repeat yourself wherever possible.

Finally, I changed every instance of compGames to computerGames in the edit function as this was a simple syntax error.

I've tried to explain this the best I can but scope can be pretty complicated to get your head around so ask me if you have any questions. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help!